# How to split list with (x, y) pairs

Tags: python, list, split

Basically I have a cheap text based ticketek system as a school project and I'm trying to let the user look at their cart, I used the the 
`list(collection.count(order_list).items())` and ended with an output something like this `[(ticket1, 8), (ticket2, 4), (ticket3, 3)]`
However I want to write a print statement that goes like: 8x ticket 1...
But that requires me to split the pairs up.

My expected result would be in the format of: `[[ticket1, 8],[ticket2, 6],[ticket3, 2]`

Comment: What format is `order_list` in?

Comment: Your given output does not seem to be valid. There are at least some quotation marks missing.

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a list to reference the output. if you iterate over `result = list(collection.count(order_list).items())` you can access each element like so: `for i in result: print(i[0],i[1])`

Comment: if the output is to just print them in a specific manner, I would suggest looking into f-strings or string formatting etc. Like Oscar has below

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to convert the result of `Counter` to a list:

```
result = [('ticket1', 8), ('ticket2', 4), ('ticket3', 3)]

for ticket, number in result:
    print("{}x {}".format(number, ticket))
```

But if you insist on it, here's s simple way do to it:

```
list(map(list, result))
=> [['ticket1', 8], ['ticket2', 4], ['ticket3', 3]]
```